# How to reinstall Chrome on Windows

Tags: windows, google-chrome

Looks to me that the only way to reinstall chrome on windows is to uninstall it and reintall it manually. Is there an easier way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

There are windows package managers like [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) that can do the trick.
After you have chocolatey, you can type into the console:

```
choco install googlechrome
choco uninstall googlechrome
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of uninstalling and installing again you could try this.

---

1. Close Google Chrome
2. Open the File epxlorer
3. Navigate to `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\`
4. Delete the folder called `Google`

This will essentially factory reset google chrome. When you next open Google Chrome it will be as if you had opened it for the first time.

**NOTE:** this will sign you out of chrome, delete all installed extensions and bookmarks. But it will **NOT** delete your Google account or any data associated with it.